# Disable Voice but Keep Data (and Texting)

Tags: iphone

I am soon traveling abroad and my phone plan includes unlimited data and texting but charges for phone calls. If I need to place a call I can always use FaceTime or WhatsApp. However, as a precaution I was wondering if there are settings to disable voice but keep data on an iPhone. Texting doesn’t matter much to me much but bonus if it can be left on.

Comment: Have you try ´´Do not disturb´´ mode ? You can block voice from anyone and still use your data and texting. The only thing is that you can still call someone by mistake...

Comment: @EddGrowl That’s a great idea! Ideally it would protect against both but I am definitely more worried about me mindlessly answering some call than accidentally placing a call.